# write.lock issue in apache solr using AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I am using AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory for Auto Suggest feature in our application.But when I try to use auto suggest feature and search for terms in the text box after some time it throws a write.lock error.
Below is my configuration in solr-config.xml file for the suggestor / suggest component and suggest request handler :

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">text</str>
    <str name="weightField">price</str>
    <str name="payloadField">prod_id</str>
    <str name="contextField">ancestors</str>  
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>  
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Any idea or solution  how I can circumvent this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Also I tried making following changes in solr-config.xml file in indexConfig :                                                                          <indexConfig>

    <lockType>${solr.lock.type:native}</lockType>

     <infoStream>true</infoStream>
  <writeLockTimeout>10000</writeLockTimeout>
  <commitLockTimeout>15000</commitLockTimeout>
  <!-- <unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>  -->

  </indexConfig>

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory`, switching to `AnalyzingLookupFactory` fixed it for me.